# Is there a way to still have full-screen Splash images in Cordova-Android 11+?

Tags: android, cordova

It appears that starting with Android 11, you are now required to include a `AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` preference in your Cordova `config.xml` that includes a path to a path to a png/xml file and the `<splash>` tags are no longer supported.

This appears to mean that we are now required to use an icon for the Splash loading in the app.

Do we have the ability to still use a full-screen image that we had done with previous versions of Android?

When using `cordova-res` it would generate some individual files for different screen sizes/densities, so I wasn't sure if there was a similar tool to help create an individual screen image for the project.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to set a full-screen splash image for an android app anymore. The `<splash>` tag are no longer supported.

To workaround this situation I'm doing the following:

1. Set an image referecing my app's icon or similar:

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/brandImage.png" />
```

2. Set a background color for the splash screen:

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#ffffff" />
```

3. Set a background color for the splash screen's icons:

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor" value="#c0c0c0" />
```

Althought this isn't the best solution, it works just fine for me.
I Hope it might helped.

Useful links:

[Splash screen configuration example - Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/core/features/splashscreen/#example-configuration)

[Splash screen Dimensions - Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions)

Comment: My splash screen has a vertical line from top to bottom, and now the line is only in the center of the screen. What can I do?

Comment: Perhaps it's happening due the image you're using for splash screen. Did You try using the same image used to create your app's icon? I think it'll fit better.

Comment: In the end I used the app icon image. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, and this is [because of Android](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions).

> The splash screen icon uses the same specifications as Adaptive icons,
> as follows:
>
> Branded image: This should be 200×80 dp. App icon with an icon
> background: This should be 240×240 dp, and fit within a circle of 160
> dp in diameter. App icon without an icon background: This should be
> 288×288 dp, and fit within a circle of 192 dp in diameter.

Comment: Bummer. Seems like a downgrade for Android users.

Comment: @zeropsi for sure, especially since us hybrid mobile devs can't make use of the "branded image", since the compatibility library that Google released (included in `cordova-android@11`) doesn't cater for it... tl;dr: we can only now use an icon and a background colour, for both the launcher icon and launch splash screen.